# use ...ing as noun or use a regular noun?

Tags: sentence-construction

Which one of the following is correct or more natural?

> One of my greatest strengths is **critically analyzing.**

or

> One of my greatest strengths is **critical analysis.**

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: The second one is more natural. "Critical Analysis" is the strength. The first one is saying that "critically analysing" is a strength, which doesn't sound natural.

Some irrelevant filler:

If you read the first sentence in a different way, you could interpret the sentence as saying that one of your strengths is in the act of critically analysing. No one would read it this way first time round, but because you *can* interpret it this way, the sentence becomes slightly ambiguous, so you should avoid it.

You can reword the sentence by adding in a few more words:

> One of my greatest strengths is the **ability** to **analyse**.

The 'ability' is the noun, so there is no ambiguity, and the 'analyse' is the action you can carry out. This gives you the best of both worlds.